# Task "Resaving all localizable elements" is stuck when adding new new locale

Tags: localization, craft-pro, tasks

I'm trying to add a new locale, but the task "Resaving all localizable elements" is stuck and the new locale is not being added to content.
Even after restarting the task.

There are no errors in the log file.

Comment: I'd start by going through this guide: https://craftcms.com/support/stuck-tasks

Comment: @BradBell Yes, I have already done that.

Answer (score 1):

As from Craft 3.1.15 you could use the `resave/entries` console command if you want  to offload entry saving to the terminal in order to update your content.

Please note that you should enable propagating entries across all enabled sites (see [documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sites.html#propagating-entries-across-all-enabled-sites)).